# django admin url not found and missing path

Tags: django, django-admin

my Django config (settings and url) like the one in the tutorial.
If I call `http://127 0 0 1:8000/admin/` I become an 404 error with the following message:
`"/Users/x/projects/foobar/admin" is not there`...

reinstall Django with pip: same error, call python manage.py syncdb: same error.

What goes on and how can I fix it?

Thanks for every help.

Comment: Is admin installed in settings.py?

Comment: Yes like this:INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',)

Comment: To commet this line in urls resolve my problem: #url(r'^(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

Answer (score 0):

To commet this line in urls resolve my problem:

```
#url(r'^(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

So I must think about to handle my dynamic image load config. But this is a other point.

Thanks!